# I've changed my password with using bell character in Windows 10

Tags: windows, change-password, alt-codes

I accidentally wrote "net user Administrator \active:yes" instead of "net user Administrator /active:yes" while trying to activate the Administrator account on my computer. As a result, my computer password now includes the ASCII bell character (alt+07) and is "[alt+07]ctive:yes". However, I can't figure out how to write a control character in the password field as Windows does not allow it. Is there a way for me to input the bell character in my password?